# An activity is supposedly destroyed. Yet, It's recreated by android without me explicitly starting it?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-activity, mvp

So, I'm facing a strange behavior. I'm implementing MVP design pattern in my app.
I have 2 activities, A and B.
The presenter of activity A is listening to a socket connection to the server.
In the activity's onDestroy() method, I call a method to unregister the presenter from the socket helper class.

In case of a certain message "TYPE X" from the socket, I start a new activity B. The onDestroy() method is called normally, and the socket listener is unregistered.

Here's the weird part. When receiving a message of the same TYPE "X", activity A is recreated and activity B is restarted, repeating the whole cycle again.

The activity A:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mainActivityPresenter.terminate();
    // some code
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The presenter:

```
@Override
public void terminate() {
    socketHelper.unregisterListener(socketListener);
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Edit: added some code snippet of how I start the new activity.

```
@Override
public void showOrderActivity(int orderType) {
    Intent orderIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
    orderIntent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_CONTENT_NAME, orderType);
//        orderIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//        orderIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//        orderIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//        finishAffinity();
//        orderIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(orderIntent);
    finish();
}
```

The commented code is my trials to make sure that Activity A is destroyed.

Comment: Perhaps `onDestroy()` is not being called. Note that starting Activity B will not trigger `onDestroy()` on Activity A, in normal cases.

Comment: I checked. onDestroy() is called. I edited my questions and added some details.

Comment: Perhaps `unregisterListener()` is not doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: So, upon double checking, I discovered the reason for this behavior. It was totally my misunderstanding of a part of the business logic. Thanks for your response.